# windows server 2012 network socket debugging (winsock / netsh) - debugging tools

Tags: windows, debug, sockets, tracing

I would like to monitor and debug the way an application (FileZilla) is accessing the tcp/ip stack (socket assignments and related operations).

The application is installed on a windows server 2012 R2 azure based machine.

I'm relatively new to the topic and I'm looking for possible  ways to debug sockets operations and failures at OS server level.

Could you please advice on debugging / tracing commands / tools that might assist me with this ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could download and install Wireshark.

Comment: Hi, thank you I already have wireshark running - and I was able to identify several issues already - however the kind of debugging that I'm interested into is at OS level (TCP/IP stack -> socket allocation and operations at OS level) -> so I don't think wireshark can be of any assistance for such analysis

Comment: Perhaps look up winsock tracing or something then... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb892105(v=vs.85).aspx may be a good starting point.